# Why is xl2tpd / pppd adding a route for 192.0.0.0/8 after bringing up the link?

Tags: ipsec, l2tp, pppd

I am establishing an l2tp connection with IPSEC between two hosts and when the link comes up a route is added on the client side for 192/8 pointing out the newly established ppp interface. I can find no reference to 192/8 anywhere in /etc or in my home directory. Is this something built into the binary for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opps, just found it. It was:

```
/sbin/route add -net `echo "${PPP_LOCAL}" | cut -d'.' -f1`.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 dev ${PPP_IFACE}
```

in file /etc/ppp/ip-up

Strange that by default it wants to route the entire /8 of your pppd address, but that's easy enough to edit.